# Writing letter name pronunciations in a simple way

Tags: orthography, letter-names

Short version, I want to fill in this list of letter names suitable for use in dialog: ?, bee, cee, dee, eee?, eff, gee, aitch, eye, jay, kay, ell, em, en, oh, pee, queue/cue?, arr, ess, tee, you/yew?, vee, double you/yew?, ex, why?, zee.

Problem letters are A, E, Q, U/W, and Y.

I can find formal pronunciations like /ei/ for A, but that doesn't seem easily understandable.

Example, ""Yes, it's ABC spelled ?-bee-cee," she clarified." (I'm not interested in writing A-B-C instead.)